# Site stats for beta metas?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is there any good reason why site stats are not calculated for the beta metas?

### Beta site:

[image: I am talking about this thing]

### Beta meta site:

[image: This makes unicorn sad!]

Granted, meta metrics are secondary, but they are nonetheless important. At least I know I have missed them on several occasions — not in comparing sites just for giggles, but in evaluating the "health" of communities I actively contribute to and deeply care about.

Answer (score 5):

While I agree that it would be nice if the stats were displayed in a similar way to the parent sites, you can get the stats for any StackExchange site (including metas) by visiting:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=[api_site_parameter]
```